# GoogleApps Directory APIs To Manage Users

Tags: google-admin-sdk

i am writing a java client to manage users in directory API. i am unable to find where to start. I checked the docs and couldn't find any example on usage of the API's, it was just saying the scopes, the url's required and the format to use. But i am unable to find any examples on connectiong to the GoogleAPpps and creating user or managing them. Please provide any information or links that might be helpful .
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hey have you tried out the java client library?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/api-lib/java

It has a quickstart for directory API in Java, which should help you set up and get started.

Additionally, here is the javadoc reference for this specific API

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/

Comment: Thanks Emily.. i will look on that client library