# Listing users using Google Admin SDK in Java

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I want to list users in a domain as defined in google. I saw that it's available through the Google Admin Directory SDK.
Although, I couldn't find any examples or documentation how can I use it in Java.
I already have got the authorization part. I'm just not sure which objects should I use from the API and how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with the relevant imports

From the docs (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list)

> As an account administrator, you can also use the my_customer alias to
>   represent your account's customerId

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Users;

    public static List<User> listUser(Directory directory) throws IOException {
        Users users = directory.users().list().setCustomer("my_customer").execute();
        return users.getUsers();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question at [GoogleApps Directory APIs To Manage Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617549/googleapps-directory-apis-to-manage-users/21635779?noredirect=1#comment32718467_21635779)

You should try out the java client library.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/api-lib/java

It has a quickstart for directory API in Java, which should help you set up and get started.

Additionally, here is the javadoc reference for this specific API

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/