# Create google docs for all users using a service account

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I create a google docs using a specific account like the service account with

```
doc = service.documents().create(doc).execute();
```

I have to create a google docs for each user of a domain `entreptise.tn` using the service account `name @entreprise.tn`.

It's possible ?.
Could you please help me solving that ?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible, you will need to enable [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority) to your service account and then iterate over each user of the domain for creating the documents. Does [this other similar Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26243855) solves your question?

Comment: Hello Sir @MateoRandwolf, thanks a lot for your reply. I know that way using impersonation. I'm asking if there's a way to do that without doing impersonation. It's possible. Big thanks Sir.

Comment: Do you mean without the service account? What do you exaclty want to achieve here? Do you want to create files in other user's Drive with the service account but without impersonation?

Comment: Hello Sir @MateoRandwolf, yes that is it. I'd like to create google drive doc in `another user Drive` ( user account inside the domaine `entreprise.tn` ) using the **service account** `service@entreprise.tn` but without impersonating. It's possible ?. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: Hi ! I am afraid not, as if you don't impersonate you would just be using the service account with a different role and it couldn't access or create files and folders on behalf of different users. [Check the documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) to get to know better service accounts.